# Append images horizontally

Tags: javascript, css, image, jsp

I am trying to display the output of servlet (images) in a single row but the images get appended vertically.

This is my jsp code:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
   <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/smoothTouchScroll.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/jquery.rondell.css" type="text/css" media="all" title="Screen">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js">    </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.rondell.js"></script>
 <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/smoothTouchScroll.css" />
 <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
<style type="text/css">
#TouchScroller
{
position:relative;
width:auto;
height:auto;
}
#TouchScroller div.scrollableArea img
{
position: relative;
float: left;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width:100%;
height:50%; 
}
    </style> 
   <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.kinetic.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.smoothTouchScroll.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <div>

 <sql:setDataSource var="webappDataSource"
driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://pshrivas-eni.cwgbkmxxzso1.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/eni_support"
user="db_user" password="password123" />

 <sql:query dataSource="${webappDataSource}"
sql="select imgid,count1  from carousel_three" var="result1" />
 <div id="car1" class="carousel">    
 <div id="rondellCarousel" class="hidden">

       <c:forEach var="row" items="${result1.rows}"> 


        <img id="img" src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath }/Imagedb?id=${row.imgid}"  /> 



 </c:forEach>  
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(function() {
// Create a rondell with the 'carousel' preset and set an option
// to disable the rondell while the lightbox is displayed
$("#rondellCarousel").rondell({
  preset: "carousel",

  onAfterShift:function(idx){
     // alert(idx);
      itemLoadCallback: trigger(idx)

  }
});
});
function trigger(idx, state)
{
  //document.getElementById('TouchScroller').innerHTML=" ";
  $.ajax({
      type : "GET",
      url : "Sampleimage1",
      contentType :"application/json",
      data:{id:idx},
      success : function(data) {
            $.each(data,function(index,item){   

                 $.each(item,function(i,obj){
                     var img = $('<img id="dynamic">'); //Equivalent: $(document.createElement('img'))
                     img.attr('src','data:image/jpg;base64,' +obj.map.key );
                     img.appendTo('.scrollableArea');

              // $('.scrollableArea').append('<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' +obj.map.key+'" />');

             });
          });
      }
    });


    }
   </script>

<div id ="car2" class="carousel1">

<div id="TouchScroller">
</div>

</div>      
<script>
   $("#TouchScroller").smoothTouchScroll({ 
      continuousScrolling: true
  });
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

[This is a preview of what I currently get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0soFF.png), but I want to display all the images in a row. Please help me with this

Comment: Use the CSS tag,  not the ones you've got. Display orientation and the like are all controlled by CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `width:100%;` on your `#TouchScroller div.scrollableArea img` forces the images to occupy as much of the container as they can, I would remove this and look into:

- [display: inline-block](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) this will allow your elements to appear next to each other
- [white-space: nowrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) this will stop your elements from wrapping down to the next line (if this is what you are after)

Be sure to check the width of the container (`.TouchScroller`) to make sure that it is the full width of the page. This is normally done via `width:100%;`

Comment: even when i change width to 60% only the images shrink but are displayed the same